# List parameter not working inside function

Tags: python-2.7, list, function, parameters

Lets say I have 4 empty variables and a 2 lists:

```
v1 = ""
v2 = ""
v3 = ""
v4 = ""

list_1 = ['2', '7', '18', '3']
list_2 = ['75', '8', '0', '13']
```

Now I want to create a function that will assign a value to the empty variables using the list as a parameter:

```
def assigner(list_a):
    for item in list_a:
      v1 = list_a[0]
      v2 = list_a[1]
      v3 = list_a[2]
      v4 = list_a[3]
```

So, I call the function, and then try a variable to check to see if the new value has been assigned based off of the list. But all I see is `''`. What is wrong here?

```
   assigner(list_1)
   print(v2)
   >>> ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v1, ..., v4` defined inside `assigner` are local to that function and do not affect those that were defined outside of it. Any half-decent IDE would have shown a warning that these local variables shadow global ones with the same name.

Not related, but that loop has no useful purpose.

Using a function here is superfluous, you can just unpack the list:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = ['2', '7', '18', '3']
```

If you insist on using a function (or if you have a need for a function, ie have some logic instead of simply assigning), make sure to `return` the variables from the function:

```
# no need to define v1, ..., v4 outside

def assigner(list_a):
    v1 = list_a[0]
    v2 = list_a[1]
    v3 = list_a[2]
    v4 = list_a[3]   
    # some magic logic
    return v1, v2, v3, v4

v1, v2, v3, v4 = assigner(list_1)
```

Some people will suggest to actually use `global` variables, but 9/10 times that would be a bad suggestion.